# Objects falls through the ground

Tags: java, collision-detection, physics

Im programming a 2D Ball-SideScroller in Java using LWJGL.

My current problem is, that i have some sort of non deterministic behavior. If i press the 'R'-Button in my application - the Constructor of the main Class ("World") is called, but the position of the ball is changing nearly every time.

Here one ScreenShot that will explain the Situation:

http://img5.picload.org/image/lcopowc/landingpoint_0.png

upper-left: this is where the ball hits the ground - of course it should roll down then

upper-right: thats what happend here - quite ok, although there are 2 or 3 pixels between ball and ground

lower-left: the third is even worse - 80% of the ball is in the ground

lower-right: and last but not least - the worst ... here the ball just ignored the slope it landed on

i tried the following things to fix this problem:

- changed the rendering from immediate to VBO
- added a thread that updates the coordinates all the time (every ms)
- checked the FPS-Rate, which is constant at 60

here some code from the method "ballReachedGround" although im not sure if the problem is really in that method

```
private boolean ballReachedGround(double slope) {
    if (velocityX > 0) {
        return checkFallRight(slope);
    } else if (velocityX < 0) {
        return checkFallLeft(slope);
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean checkFallRight(double slope) {
    if (ball.getY() + ball.getTransy() + ball.getRadius() >= realY2) {
        double xdiff = (ball.getX() + ball.getTransx() + ball.getRadius()) % 50;
        double actualHeight = realY1 + (xdiff / 50) * (realY2 - realY1);
        if (slope < Math.tan(Math.toRadians(-45))) {
            if (ball.getY() + ball.getTransy() + ball.getRadius() >= actualHeight) {
                if (ball.getY() + ball.getTransy() >= actualHeight) {
                    velocityX = 0;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(slope);
        } else {
            double angle = Math.toDegrees((Math.atan(slope)));
            double anglediff = ball.getRotate() - angle;
            ball.setTransy(ball.getTransy() - velocityX * timediff
                    * Math.tan(Math.toRadians(anglediff)));
            if (ball.getY() + ball.getTransy() + 40 >= actualHeight) {
                return true;
            }
            System.out.println(slope);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is definitely in one of these two: 1) Your collision and dynamics code is buggy 2) Your rendering is off: the world is moving, but the ball isn't, or vise versa. Showing us a video might help.

Comment: Also, not sure if your goal in your thesis is to write a physical engine or not, but there are plenty of good working engines out there. My personal favorite is Box2D.

Comment: yea developing the needed physical engine is one main part of the thesis, so using existings engines will not work ^^ ... so here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNdbZY3mKhU             hope u can see the problem - otherwise i can make another longer one

Comment: The video was pretty clear. So your physics are wrong. Once you detected a collision, you should move the body out of your static scenery (=ground) the shortest way possible. That is how physical engines work. So, in other words, your parabolic trajectory of the ball seems good, but because of this is a simulation, it makes steps, so it isn't a continuous path. One frame it will be above the ground, and the next frame, it will be in the ground. Once you detected that, move the ball back up the closest way out. On edges, this might go to left or right, if you bounce against walls.

Comment: Hello, as i had to change nearly every part of my code it needed some time, but here is the 2nd video =) ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlQizeYQebs ... so as you can see the thing what i called "non-deterministic behavior" is fixed - the landing point of the ball is nearly fix, and even the code is much easier to read. Many many thanks to you Martijn, you really helped me! There's still of course much work to do, now the ball is hopping which is a bit annoying but im looking forward to fix the issues and implement new stuff =) once again THANK YOU ^^

Comment: Glad to help. I added an answer so you can close this question by accepting my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video was pretty clear. So your physics are wrong. Once you detected a collision, you should move the body out of your static scenery (=ground) the shortest way possible. That is how physical engines work. So, in other words, your parabolic trajectory of the ball seems good, but because of this is a simulation, it makes steps, so it isn't a continuous path. One frame it will be above the ground, and the next frame, it will be in the ground. Once you detected that, move the ball back up the closest way out. On edges, this might go to left or right, if you bounce against walls.